# Javascript eval alias

Tags: javascript

Does javascript allow aliasing eval?
The first part of the following code behaves unexpectedly (displays 1, 1), but the second part does not (displays 1, 2).
A reference to the ECMA script or mozilla docs will be helpful, I couldn't find one.

```
<html>
<script type="application/javascript;version=1.8">
    (function(){
        eval('var testVar=1');
        alert(testVar);
        var eval2=eval;
        eval2('var testVar=2');
        alert(testVar);
    })();

    (function(){
        eval('var testVar=1');
        alert(testVar);
        eval('var testVar=2');
        alert(testVar);
    })();
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: How is the first one's result unexpected?

Comment: When `eval` is not aliased, it displays 1, 2, see the second function. If it is expected, can you answer the question? Thanks.

Comment: Yes but you said the first one behaves unexpectedly by displaying 1 and 2. That's expected.

Comment: Sorry got the order wrong, updated question.

Comment: Chrome, Firefox and IE9 behave the same. Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7d7Rz/ .

Comment: "*any invocation of eval that is not a direct call uses the **global environment** as its variable environment rather than the caller’s variable environment.*" [ECMAScript 5 standard, Annex E](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-E)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't "alias" `eval` and expect it to behave the same. Simple as that. Why? `eval` isn't a function.

What is happening is that when you call `eval2`, you are setting the variable "cache" to work with the global variables. Therefore, by setting a variable inside of it, you are setting a global variable. However, upon exiting, the variable "cache" returns back to the function scoped one. That's why the second `alert` shows 1 - the global variable is being shadowed by the function level one.

This is noted in Annex E (page 239) of ECMAScript (emphasis mine)

> 10.4.2: In Edition 5, **indirect calls to the eval function** use the **global environment as both the variable environment** and lexical environment for the eval code. In Edition 3, the variable and lexical environments of the caller of an indirect eval was used as the environments for the eval code.

The full definition on "Entering Eval Code" is defined in §10.5.2 (page 58) (emphasis mine)

1. If there is no calling context or **if the eval code is not being evaluated by a direct call** (15.1.2.1.1) to the eval function then,

   - **Initialise the execution context as if it was a global execution context** using the eval code as C as described in 10.4.1.1.
2. Else,

   - Set the ThisBinding to the same value as the ThisBinding of the calling execution context.
   - Set the LexicalEnvironment to the same value as the LexicalEnvironment of the calling execution
     context.
   - Set the VariableEnvironment to the same value as the VariableEnvironment of the calling execution
     context.
3. If the eval code is strict code, then

   - Let strictVarEnv be the result of calling NewDeclarativeEnvironment passing the LexicalEnvironment as the argument.
   - Set the LexicalEnvironment to strictVarEnv.
   - Set the VariableEnvironment to strictVarEnv.
4. Perform Declaration Binding Instantiation as described in 10.5 using the eval code.

Comment: If `eval` is not a function, why `alert(eval)` shows `function eval() { [native code] }`?

Comment: Your first part is incorrect, aliasing `eval` does work in firefox, and there are no errors raised, but not as I expect. Try `eval2(alert("test"))`. In fact, the ECMA spec says "Implementations are no longer permitted to restrict the use of eval in ways that are not a direct call. In addition".

Comment: You're misreading the standard. `eval` *can* be aliased, but then it will work differently. See the other parts of the standard: "*Eval code is the source text supplied to the **built-in eval function.***" (#10.1), "*or if the eval code is not being evaluated by a **direct call***" (#10.4.2) and others.

Comment: `Calling null would do nothing` Calling null would throw an error, no?

Comment: @ColeJohnson But still: "`eval() is a top-level function...`" [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Description).

Answer (score 2):

In the first case when you use `eval`, it uses the function scope within which it is executed. When you assign `eval` to `eval2` and then execute the same statement, it seems to be using the `window` context(global scope) and not the function context. That's why you see the same value 1 in the first case because `testVar` inside the function is 1 and outside `window.testVar` is 2. You can prove this by executing the below snippet

```
<script>
(function(){
        eval('var testVar=1');
        alert(window.testVar);
        var eval2=eval;

        eval2('var testVar=2');
        alert(window.testVar);
    })();

    (function(){
        eval('var testVar=1');
        alert(testVar);
        eval('var testVar=2');
        alert(testVar);
    })();
</script>
```

Actually, as per [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), you can't alias eval.